# MapServer inside WordPress Pages/Posts?

Tags: mapserver, mapscript

I'd like to put maps inside of a wordpress CMS, but I'm running into troubles with the permalink structure ignoring the maps all together...

I have a .htaccess file that will force WordPress to ignore a directory, and I can have the page render, but not inside the pages...

I've tried embedding an iframe, both from an .htaccess allowed directory, and even from a subdomain that has nothing but a test map on it.

I'm fairly new to GIS, so any help in connecting a MapServer / MapScript system into WordPress would be genuinely appreciated.

If there's any other data you need, please let me know.

Matt

Comment: Hey matt, this sounds like it might be more of a wordpress question than a GIS question.  You might have better luck elsewhere.  That being said, AFAIK, MapScript produces images, which need to be linked to.  In PHPmapscript, you'd need to do $img = $map->draw(), and then $img->save('c:\my_web_folder\images\mymap.gif').  Then your page would need an <img src="/images/mymap.gif">.

Comment: all of which is to say, i don't know anything about wordpress, and am assuming you should be able to link to the image, just like any other image.